# Exporting armature animation using gtlf exporter for blender 2.82 error

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I have been spending days now trying to export a GLTF file, but each time I export, an error occurs while viewing different animations in the GLTF online viewer.

For Example, if I export two rigged objects with animation, in the GLTF viewer the Object 1 will play both its own animation and the other object animation.

Object 2 will remain static like it has no animation. I have tried to fix it but it seems there is no solution.

Comment: See the guide in the [glTF addon docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html) about animation. You'll need to assign animations to objects, either as active Actions, stashed Actions, or NLA Tracks. Otherwise there is no association between the animation and the object.

Comment: If that isn't working, you may need to file a bug on https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO.

Comment: I think i just needed to rename some objects and all went as expected